# What is the step by step integration of ds for a great circle in terms of spherical coordinates?

Tags: riemann-integration, spherical-coordinates

Wikipedia gives the metric as:

[image]

I found the equation below on line, but have not been able to find it again.

[image]

K = Gaussian curvature.

Because the circumference equation involves, K, it could be derived from the definition of Gaussian curvature near a pole shown below, not from integrating *ds*:

[image]

In which higher exponential terms of R go to zero rapidly.
R is defined as the geodesic radius, traveling over the pole.

Answer (score 1):

I am not surprised that you cannot find this formula for $C(r)$ again because it seems wrong.

To start, we should not confuse the polar coordinate $r$ with the geodesic distance $r$.
Best to forget $ds^2=dr^2+r^2\,d\theta^2+r^2\sin^2d\phi^2$ (using $r$ as a polar coordinate) completely as it is not needed. The unit sphere has radius one.

The geodesic distance from the north pole $(1,0,0)$ of a point on the unit sphere that is at $(1,\theta,0)$ is
$$
r=\theta.
$$
The circumference $C(r)$ of this [geodesic circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic_circle) with radius $r$ is $C(r)=2\pi\sin\theta=2\pi\sin r\,.$ Using the well known power series of $\sin$,
$$\tag{1}
C(r)=2\pi\Bigg\{r-\frac{r^3}{3!}+\frac{r^5}{5!}-\frac{r^7}{7!}+...\Bigg\}\,.
$$
By the [Bertrand-Diquet-Puiseux theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%E2%80%93Diguet%E2%80%93Puiseux_theorem) the Gaussian curvature is
$$
K=\lim_{r\downarrow 0}3\frac{2\pi r-C(r)}{\pi r^3}\,.
$$
Using (1) this is
$$
K=\lim_{r\downarrow 0}\frac{6}{r^3}\Bigg\{\frac{r^3}{3!}-\frac{r^5}{5!}+\frac{r^7}{7!}+...\Bigg\}=1
$$
as expected. You could obviously write (1) as
$$\tag{1}
C(r)=2\pi\Bigg\{r-\frac{Kr^3}{3!}+\frac{Kr^5}{5!}-\frac{Kr^7}{7!}+...\Bigg\}
$$
but that's a fairly useless improvement for the unit sphere.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Im confused because it seems plane geometry is mixed in. I must misunderstand somethung Saying C = 2 pi sin(theta)-isn't that true if the circle us a plane circle?  The geodesic circle is on the sphere, not a plane circle. And i thought r=theta would only be true if R (polar radius) x dtheta=ds, the arc kength element. But the metric is dufferent for a sohere. I know you said discard the metric i referenced, but using it would make r not equal theta.

Comment: I have added the link that defines [geodesic circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic_circle). In our case it is a circle with radius $r$ around the north pole. That $r$ is measured on the surface (like we measure all distances on earth). This circle is also a circle in a *plane* around a point below the earth's surface. To figure out its radius $\sin\theta$ in that plane is a matter of elementary geometry. Isn't it ?

Comment: For example. The geodesic distance of the equator to the north pole is $\pi/2\approx 1.57\,.$ The radius of the equator is $1.0$.

Comment: I had read that wiki definition. I forgot inside the sphere regular trig holds. No curvature to the radius or its projection sin (theta). But the equatorial to pole distance is not exactly pi/2, right? The circumference is not exactly 2 pi.  It is really the convergent sum above. . Ds is not exactly d(theta). Integrating d(theta) would produce full arc length (pi/2 in your example) only if ds were d(theta). Is r=theta an approximation that is good enough for the solution?

Comment: Sorry if i seem to be stuck on the issue of the metric.  its the only basic feature of the sphere i can think of to account for the fact that the circumference is not exactly the same as that of a plane circle. Maybe it is irrelevant to your statement that r=theta.

Comment: Your last equation contains K, which is a form of the metric (determinant of matrix). So, it (my original ds at the beginning of my post) is relevant but must be insignificant in leading to any discrepancy in the equation r =theta. As an amateur, i dont know why the metric (as K) is needed in your final equation but is of little consequence in the equality of theta and the geodesic radius.

Comment: Any discrepancy in r would be small so higher powers of r for r<= 1 would vanish just as quickly. For r>= 1 a small discrepancy, resulting from any approximation, would still not keep pace with the factorial. As you said pi/2 is its max anyway. K on the other hand is large for small spheres. Hence signuficant.

Comment: In your last four comments I read a lot of stuff I have to disagree with. 1) We have an ideal sphere of radius $R=1$. Therefore the pole to equator distance is $R\pi/2$ simply because that's one quarter of a round trip which has distance $2\pi R$. Now take $R=1$. 2) The circumference of any great circle on our sphere is *exactly* $2\pi R$. Take $R=1$. 3) The convergent sum above is $C(r)=2\pi\sin r\,.$ That is -as I tried to explain in my earlier comments- the circumference of a circle that lies in a *plane* and is *also* a geodesic circle with geodesic distance of $r$ from the north pole.

Comment: 4) The Gaussian curvature is a *number* not a matrix. For the sphere of radius $R$ it is $1/R^2$. Take $R=1$. 5) I am an differential geometric amateur myself. Learnt that stuff just from Wikipedia.

Comment: I will do some web searches. I will include any url in my next comment. I distinctly remember reading a great circlr circumfetence is always less than 2 pi r. And that on an hyperboloid is greater than 2 pi r. That is the source of my confusion.

Comment: I got a response from a guy who works at MAA. Im waiting until after the weekend to follow up.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, maybe you've moved on. The MAA guy didn't follow up. I plan on stopping by a former math teacher's office during office hours monday instead.

Comment: I am following this post. Take your time. No rush.

Comment: I ended up with covid last week so my visit with the math professor is not this coming MOnday.

Comment: @GaryW . Stay safe and recover soon!

Comment: Tested negative for covid. I met with the Professor who said the two circumferences are the same provided the same metric is used. He said the curved metric on a sphere would look straight if one could zoom in. Of course one can't-,we can't see the infinitesimal. The question remains: if a riemann metric is used on a sphere, what is used on the plane circle? The flat olane does not admit a curved metric. He said one can use a euclidean metric, cartesian or spherical coor., and arrive at the same answer for circumference. I think ill start a new post.

Comment: Have you digested and discussed with your Professor the [Bertrand-Diquet-Puiseux-Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%E2%80%93Diguet%E2%80%93Puiseux_theorem)? It is a very intuitive way to define Gaussian curvature on the sphere. If we had the freedom to measure the radius (which leads to circumference) of the geodesic circle in two flat metrics the Gaussian curvature would become zero which is absurd. Use the two correct metrics (Riemann on the sphere and flat in space) and you are done.